# Is there a name for this property of a real function?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, special-functions

Let $M=\sup_{x \in [0,1]^n} f(x)$ where $f:[0,1]^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable twice, and write $x=(x_1, \dots, x_n)$.
Let $M_{x_i=0}=\sup_{x \in [0,1]^n:x_i=0} f(x)$ and $M_{x_i=1}=\sup_{x \in [0,1]^n:x_i=1} f(x)$.

I have a set of functions such that $M \leq  M_{x_i=0} + M_{x_i=1} \forall i$.
Has this sort of property been studied?  Does it have a name?
Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: I can't imagine that such a thing would have a name, or be studied for its own sake.